Open source, free Download Manager (Alternative to Download Accelerator Plus and Internet Download Manager)
I'm looking for a free, open-source alternative to download managers such as DAP (Download Accelerator Plus) and Internet Download Manager, which are both paid.
I've seached for alternatives but really just found paid alternatives. It would be nice for it to be open-source for the possibility of contributing.

Have you check JDownloader? https://jdownloader.org/

https://github.com/pyload/pyload
The last release was in February 2020, but the last commits were 4 days ago.
That is, the project is active and can most likely be launched from the master.
https://github.com/agalwood/Motrix
The last release was in May 2023, the last commit was also a year ago.
It has not been developed for quite a long time, but it may still be working and performing its functions.

Perfect! Thanks :)
